# Identity in C# ASP.NET Core Web API user

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, identity

I have a project it's about real estate so I created tables `user` and linked it with `estates`, and I learnt about identity.

When I migrate it hides the `user` table because the ASP.NET Core identity already has a `users` table, so how can I link asp.net user to users or how to link asp.net user to identity user

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Try.DAL.Entity
{
        [Table("Users")]
    public class Users
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Fname { get; set; }
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Lname { get; set; }

        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        [StringLength(20)]
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public DateTime Signupdate { get; set; }

        public int Usergroupid { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Usergroupid")]
        public UserGroup Usergroup { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Estate> Estate { get; set; }
   

    }
}




 
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Try.DAL.Entity;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Try.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
//using Try.Models;

namespace Try.DAL.Database
{
    public class DbContainer : IdentityDbContext
    {
        public DbContainer(DbContextOptions<DbContainer> opts) : base(opts) { }
        public virtual DbSet<RefreshToken> RefreshTokens { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Users> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Ads> Ads { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Clients> Clients { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Feedback> Feedback { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Interests> Interests { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Orders> Orders { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Estate> Estate { get; set; }
        public DbSet<users> users{ get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your Dbcontext class as below:

```
public class UserTestDbContext : IdentityDbContext

{
    public UserTestDbContext(DbContextOptions<UserTestDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<_3._7.Models.User> User { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("User");
    }
}
```

And I have simpfied the  class  as below:

public class User:IdentityUser

```
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
   
    public string Password { get; set; }
  }
```

Result:
The migration class:
[image: migration]
and the database:

[image: DB1]
[image: DB2]

And if you modify the dbcontext class as follow:

```
public class UserTestDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
{
    public UserTestDbContext(DbContextOptions<UserTestDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<_3._7.Models.User> User { get; set; }    
}
```

You could find the properties of user class has been added to the ASPNetUser Table.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the fields you want to add to the identity users table in the `applicationDbContext.cs` file like this:

```
namespace Try.DAL.Database
{
    // You add this class here with custom fields.
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        // add properties here.
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Fname { get; set; }
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Lname { get; set; }

        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        [StringLength(20)]
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public DateTime Signupdate { get; set; }

        public int Usergroupid { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Usergroupid")]
        public UserGroup Usergroup { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Estate> Estate { get; set; }
    }

    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
        public DbSet<Users> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Ads> Ads { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Clients> Clients { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Feedback> Feedback { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Interests> Interests { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Orders> Orders { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Estate> Estate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: if this answered the question, please consider marking it as the excepted answer.